# Sailsjs not getting email when using node mailer smtp transport

Tags: smtp, sails.js, nodemailer

I am using node mailer to send emails in my sailsjs application.But unable to get emails when using smtp transport to send emails. It is showing the correct response with meesage id in callback method but am not getting email in my mailbox. Here is some configuration I made for smtp transport:

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');

var transport = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    host: 'smtp.hostname.com',
    port: 587,
    debug: true,
    auth: {
        user: 'XXXXXX',
        pass: 'XXXXXX'
    }
}));
```

And am using following method to send email:

```
var mailOptions = {
    from: 'Sendername  <sender@noreply.com>', // sender address
    to: reciever@domain.com, // list of receivers
    subject: Email Subject, // Subject line
    text: 'Hello world ', // plaintext body

};

transport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
    }else{
        console.log('Message sent: ' , info);
    }
});
```

And the following response am getting after send email:

```
   Message sent:  
      { accepted: [ 'reciever@domain.com' ],
      rejected: [],
      response: '250 OK id=1XeiXV-00005O-6x',
      envelope: { from: 'sender@noreply.com', to: [ 'reciever@domain.com' ] },
      messageId: '1413456251972-47ace346-09f25dad-5616cfdb@noreply.com' }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your app deployed to a host or are you running it locally?  Host's like Modulus often block SMTP ports because of spammers.